# Background service attempts count mechanism

Tags: sql, design-patterns, error-handling, windows-services, background-process

There is a .net windows service, which processes portions of data within a table in ms sql server.

Obviously, sometimes an errors occur during transaction an then i want to skip the failured record and return to it later. The first way is to have AttemptsCount column, increment it on error and check it's value in the select query. But there are some issues, like how to save AttemptsCount during rollback etc.

So what are the ways of compensation mechanisms for such situation? It's clear for me in case of message queues, sql jobs, but windows service working with sql. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your record bears a business value, then I am not very happy about mixing it with a technical-only column such as `AttemptsCount` in general. So your issues with rollback are just a "deserved punishment" for breaking a design principles.

What about creating a kind of a **error log** holding record IDs of records where an error occurred. You may implement it in any way: an extra table, a queue, ... You may then process the error log times by times ("i want to ... return to it later"). Of course you should write into this log not within the original transaction itself, but rather outside of it.

Thus you will reach several goals:

- Separate your business data (records) from the technical data (error info)
- "Promote" your error handling to a kind of a business process - this may sounds funny with regard to the previous point but it's true at the same time :) - and this process is independent.
- You may ass further logic to it, such as recording the timestamp of each error, store all the errors to an archive, perform some error statistics, ...